# event.preventDefault not working in form select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to disable click to select value in select box. I use event.preventDefault but it not working. Help me.

Comment: then what do you want if you dont want click event ??

Answer (score 0):

Use disabled attribute

```
<select disabled="true">
    <option value="1">test data 1</option>
    <option value="2">test data 2</option>
    <option value="3">test data 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: in html5 you just need `<select disabled>`

Comment: but. i want to unbin click to event different